# Add marker on map by tap and hold on location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've managed to create an google API and use maps and read guides, but none of them solves the following feature:

- Tap and hold on a certain location to add a marker

In most of existing guides it is explained how to make "hard burned" markers, but that's not the case. Eg. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Can someone help me on this one?

Answer (score 0):

These should work for you:

```
function tapHold(map, length)
{
    this.length_ = length;
    var me = this;
    me.map_ = map;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function(e) { me.onMouseDown_(e) });
    };

tapHold.prototype.onMouseDown_ = function() { this.down_ = +new Date; };
new tapHold(map, 300);
google.maps.event.addListener( map,
                               'longpress',
                               function(event) 
                               {
                                   <YOUR CODE>
                                   };
                               );
```

Comment: Thanks. I've followed the link in the description above. May be a noob question, but where am I going to put the code?